# Calculate weighted average of a data subset with one column as weights

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge data set and I need to calculate a weighted average for subsets. My approach works but is painfully slow (dozens of minutes on my data) and I would like to find a faster solution. I thought to use DataFrame.agg but I cannot find out how to put a second column as the weight.

So far, I build a new DataFrame, an aggregated dataframe, with .apply, see below

```
def weighted(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('spot')
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    for column in df.columns:
        result[column] = grouped.apply(weighted_average, column, 'weight')
    return result


def weighted_average(df, target_column, weight_column):
    """The average of a target column is calculated with a second column as weight.
    Input:
        DataFrame
        string for column to average
        string for column as weight
    Output:
        float, weighted average of target column """
    return sum(df[weight_column] * df[target_column]) / df[weight_column].sum()
```

Thanks for your attention & help.

Update: I gained a factor 100 timed with 1/250 of my data by doing the following:

```
def tot_weighting(df, weight_column, list_of_columns):
    norm = df.groupby('spot')[weight_column].transform('sum')
    for column in list_of_columns:
         df[column] = df[weight_column] * df[column]/norm
    result = df.groupby('spot').agg('sum')
    return result
```

Comment: please post a reproducible example, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try  **np.vectorize** of the numpy module instead, it's faster, I'm pretty sure your code could be less and faster.